# Why aren't my questions getting answered?

Tags: discussion

Firstly, let me say that I am a question abuser and have not answered enough questions myself. This comes from my opinion of myself that I am not a developer of enough caliber yet to answer correctly. I may actually be wrong about this, you can look through my asked questions and maybe tell me I should try answering a few more questions now!

I am just saying that I have noticed a big drop off in the response I get to my questions now.

I'm not saying I don't like this and I want more, or that I want people to look at my questions! I"m stating it here to see if anyone else agrees and if there is something we can do? If it's happening here it's surely going to happen across the stack exchange as a whole?

Comment: A post like this pops up every few days. I'm not aware of any significant changes to SO recently, so I'm going to say this is a random lull for you until there's more evidence.

Comment: I wouldn't consider 70 questions/24 answers a "question abuser". That seems like a pretty good ratio.

Comment: As an aside, don't think of yourself as too low caliber.  I'm nowhere near the caliber on SO of most of the devs and yet have 2300+ rep.  Just keep looking for things you can answer and when you do find something, answer it!!

Comment: Just as an aside, it's a statistical certainty that if everyone asks more questions than they answer, you'll get questions without any answers ;)

Comment: I just seem to come across these people that have loads of answers, and no questions? Are these people superhuman, or don't like asking questions?

Comment: @Chris Barry: No, they're just experienced.  I know this is going to be hard to believe, but there were software developers before there was an Internet.  You either figured it out, or you couldn't finish your work.

Comment: @ChrisBarry: Some of us have gotten better at spotting questions we have answers for because we run across the problems all the time so we are able to decipher quickly what the question asker wants.

Answer (score 10):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7311523/c-turning-a-nested-set-query-into-a-object-hierarchy-to-convert-to-json-for-ext) is pretty long so it might not get many answers. Try trimming it down.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6102589/allowing-custom-tags-in-tinymce-for-intergration-with-indexhibit) might benefit from a bounty. It seems you are asking a question for a low-popularity tinymce tag.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743737/quick-crud-ajax-for-asp-net-mvc-project) has too many questions associated with it. Consider breaking it apart. It could even be closed as not-a-real-question.

That's just a sampling of your unanswered questions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers much appreciated..